# Have to reopen Chrome to have the sound again?

Tags: audio, google-chrome

I don't know if anyone has this problem which is:

When I connect my headphone or disconnect it from my macbook pro. The video, music in Chrome don't work anymore ( it's mute ). I have to reopen Chrome to make them work.

Do we have any solution to fix this ?

Comment: Does it happen with any other application? Other user?

Comment: other user ? I haven't tried all other apps. But spotify has the same problem, I have to wait a bit of time and restart the app.